# Selenium: handle javascript alert with IE in facebook php-webdriver

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to accept an IE javascript alert using using the php webdriver for selenium
This works for FF and Chrome, but IE fails

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$web_driver = new WebDriver();
// opens Internet explorer browser
$session = $web_driver->session('internet explorer');
// Navigates to page that has JS alert on close.
$session->open('http://mypage.com/');
// Closes Offer window
$session->deleteWindow();
// Accepts alert to leave page
$session->accept_alert(); // Except accept_alert isn't working correctly in IE
// Closes last window
$session->close();
// Kill session for garbage collection
unset($session);
```

I know there's [this answer for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682904/handling-javascript-alerts-in-selenium) and [this answer for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114037/selenium-webdrive-and-checking-alert-messages), but am looking for a PHP specific solution since the java methods aren't the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one took me forever to figure out. What I have done before is after the `deleteWindow()` call, grab the newest window handle and set the focus to it. Once you have the alert in focus you can call `accept_alert()` on it and the window will close as expected. Here's the idea.

```
$web_driver = new WebDriver();
$session = $web_driver->session('internet explorer');
$session->open('http://mypage.com/');
$session->deleteWindow();

// Here's the new part
$handles = $this->_session->window_handles(); // stores array of window handles
$new_handle = end($handles); // grabs the newest handle, in this case our alert
$this->_session->focusWindow($new_handle); // gives the alert window focus

// Should now work as expected
$session->accept_alert();
$session->close();
unset($session);
```

This will also work for the firefox and chrome drivers, so you can use the same code for all drivers if you wanted to. Good luck!

Comment: $capabilities = array(WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');

$driver = new WebDriver($wd_host, $capabilities);

How do I get session from this?