# How can I close a javascript popup in selenium (Facebook/php-webdriver)?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The error thrown is UnexpectedAlertOpenWebDriverError, when I try to access some element on the page.

Comment: Did you try `$session->accept_alert();`?

Comment: How can I get $session. I am using $driver and use findElement(), get() etc.

Comment: Like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260301/selenium-handle-javascript-alert-with-ie-in-facebook-php-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

```
$driver->switchTo()->alert()->accept();
```

Actually, you can `dismiss`, `accept` or `cancel` the alert.

See https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/master/lib/WebDriverAlert.php.